[WARNING]: Module invocation had junk after the JSON data: (pam_mount.c:133): clean system authtok=0x55fff151e610 (1073741824)
I run the ansible playbook and receive many messages of this kind in the process. does anyone know how to get rid of them and what they mean?
> - name:    hosts: all   become: yes   gather_facts: no   tasks:
>   - name: copy files for setup
>     copy:
>       src: /home/user/files
>       dest: /home/user/files
>       force: yes
>       mode: 0644 
>   - name: Install 
>     apt:
>       deb: /home/user/files/*-client_amd64.deb
>       update_cache: true
>       state: present

I have not found a solution to this problem.

the problem is that the module is not capturing the stderr or stdout into a variable but sending it to actual stdout.
As the stdout is processed by Ansible for JSON data (result data) it finds this output which is not JSON and so it deems it garbage
